# Raw audio playback in Allegro 5

Tags: audio, playback, allegro5

I'm writing a MOD player, trying to playback a sample using Allegro5 raw stream capabilities, I can't figure out the exact init parameters for the stream to play the loaded sample data from the mod file.

This is what I have:

```
xf::ModLoader ml;
ml.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\bubu\\Downloads\\agress.mod");
// getSampleLength() returns # of data words
int sample_length = ml.getSampleLength(1) * 2;
const int8_t* sample_data = ml.getSampleData(1);

ALLEGRO_MIXER* mixer = al_get_default_mixer();
ALLEGRO_AUDIO_STREAM* stream = al_create_audio_stream(1, sample_length, 8363, ALLEGRO_AUDIO_DEPTH_INT8, ALLEGRO_CHANNEL_CONF_1);

al_attach_audio_stream_to_mixer(stream, mixer);
al_set_audio_stream_gain(stream, 0.7f);
al_set_audio_stream_playmode(stream, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE);
al_set_audio_stream_playing(stream, true);
al_set_audio_stream_fragment(stream, (void*)sample_data);
al_drain_audio_stream(stream);
```

First of all, freq param is hardcoded for the test (8363Hz), but, playing back at the specified frequency I don't get what I expect, and al_drain_audio_stream() gets stuck forever playing garbage in a loop...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you need to be calling `al_get_audio_stream_fragment` before you call `al_set_audio_stream_fragment`. Typically you'd feed these streams in a while loop, while responding to the `ALLEGRO_EVENT_AUDIO_STREAM_FRAGMENT` event. See the `ex_saw` example in the Allegro's source for some sample code: https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/master/examples/ex_saw.c